# Visualization of xsd Dependencies?

Tags: graph, xsd, visualization, dependency-management

I have a bunch of XSD Files which I did not write myself. The files sometimes import each other:

```
<xs:import namespace="http://www.mysite.com/xmlns/xXX-YYYY/V"  schemaLocation="http://www.mysite.com/xmlns/xXX-YYYY/V/schema_A.xsd"/>
```

and I would like to get an overview of the dependencies without having to read through all of them.

The URI specified by schemaLocation does not exist, instead a catalog.xml File is used to resolve the schema locations.

http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML_Catalogs

Can anybody recommend a tool that can visualize the dependencies of my schemas by also processing the information given in the catalog.xml file?

Thanks
Mischa

Comment: Requests for tool recommendations are out of scope on Stack Overflow.

Comment: You should slightly rephrase it maybe, to escape the wrath of people here... [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12386110/how-to-generate-a-dependency-diagram-from-a-set-of-xsd-files/12389979) got away with murder, if you consider the -2 you've got already... :) instead of "tool" maybe "approach" might be better... Anyway, I'll answer why a catalog will not work that easily.

Comment: @kjhughes I do not fully agree with that policy (if only its actual purpose is to suppress unauthorized advertising).
But otherwise, it may just cut off some very interesting things (and this question is particular). Look, you have some routine task. You have searched Internet and found no suitable solution. Now, you want to ask perhaps someone knows any approach. But how otherwise can you ask that?

Answer (score 0):

To follow up on my comment...

I am not aware of any tool that takes into account OASIS catalog files. Have a look at [this response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12386110/how-to-generate-a-dependency-diagram-from-a-set-of-xsd-files/19654857#19654857), see if it supports what you need (and your platform).

Strictly speaking, there are a number of issues with dependencies diagrams, which is why such a question should be qualified with why do you want it.

Some think that it truly shows dependencies between XSD files; it is not true: it may show what the author thinks the dependencies are, but that wouldn't be what the processor actually agrees to. "schemaLocation" is just a hint that processors may or may not use: "may not" use it if they're instructed otherwise (well known XSDs could be cached internally, through catalog entries or any other proprietary "catalogs"), or because the processor may decide there is no need to load an external reference when there's no use for it anyway (it may happen in some corner cases).

A diagram built as described by explicit schema locations is definitely easier to do. It only shows what the author intended; it doesn't mean that it is the "real one" (as in content is pulled indirectly, which makes the whole XSD set valid, while individual XSDs, open independently of the set, would be invalid).

Trying to build a diagram where dangling or non existing schemaLocation are overridden through a catalog, is way harder, due to the multitude of ways to structure the content, and the resolution mechanism. It would have the same shortcoming as the one above (except now the author is the one of the catalog file, rather than who authored the XSDs).

The "true" dependency can be built by traversing a schema set already loaded and compiled. Even then, you would still need to define criteria regarding dependencies due to substitutable components (elements in substitution groups or derived types, through the use of the xsi:type attribute). That is even harder.

Comment: Well, it would be enough to show dependencies between the XSD files created simply by `<xs:import>`, `<xs:include>` and `<xs:redefine>`.
I myself frequently need exactly this.
Going deeper than that is quite different problem.
For that matter, you may even think about dependencies created on the level of a particular end-user application (e.g. finance), which those XML schemas are for. So, you are right, its is impossible to visualize at once any dependencies imaginable.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this tool: **[DocFlex/XML XSDDoc](http://www.filigris.com/docflex-xml/xsddoc/)**.
It is an XML schema documentation generator.

It doesn't visualize xsd dependencies, but it does work with XML catalogs.

The overview of each XSD file lists all other XSD files referenced from it
(i.e. imported, included or redefined).
There is also an opposite list of those schemas that reference the given one.

So, you can use it to figure out which XSD files depend on which.
At least, that will be easier than reading raw XSD files.

As an example, here is a documentation generated with that tool:
[XML Schemas for DITA 1.1](http://www.filigris.com/docflex-xml/xsddoc/examples/html/dita11/index.html). It has been generated basically by two files:

- http://docs.oasis-open.org/dita/v1.1/OS/schema/ditaarch.xsd
- http://docs.oasis-open.org/dita/v1.1/OS/schema/catalog.xml

`ditaarch.xsd` is the schema driver that pulls all other schemas (25 in total); `catalog.xml` is the XML catalog, via which all file references are resolved.
What is specified in `schemaLocation` attributes in those schemas themselves are just opaque URIs.